# Tiktok login kit redirect_uri on localhost

Tags: reactjs, tiktok

I'm trying to implement the Tiktok login kit, but I'm having problems with the `redirect_uri` on localhost. Localhost can't be defined on the Tiktok developers applications, so when I reach Tiktok with `redirect_uri=localhost`, it throws an error page.

Do I need to define in my host file the real URL, or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started) that helps in these cases where you need a public url.

After installation and config you can do this in a terminal:

```
ngrok http 8000
```

And you will see something like this:

```
ngrok                                                                                                                                                         (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online
Account                       inconshreveable (Plan: Free)
Version                       3.0.0
Region                        United States (us)
Latency                       78.006541ms
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    https://84c5df439d74.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

So from the outside (any other machine not only your local pc) you can request to this url `https://84c5df439d74.ngrok.io` and will forward the requests to `localhost:8000`

Comment: Did you actually test this with TikTok api?  if so what redirect uri did you set? how long did it take for it to take effect? did it actually work?

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend @anibal answer a little more.

When you are using ngrok, you will want to set a static domain. Because everytime that you run `ngrok http 3000`, your domain will keep changing.
Once you create your static domain in your ngrok portal dashboard.

Ref here

https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/?os=windows

You then use that domain as your redirect url in your Tiktok portal.